# Django, queryset filter datetime. Show entries after today

Tags: django, datetime, filter, django-queryset

I'm trying to filter a queryset to return all the entries where the date for each entry is after today. It's a calendar and I want this for an 'Upcoming Events' feature.

I do know that my code is completely wrong but I wrote it just to show you what I'm looking for.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
events = Event.objects.filter(date_from=now).order_by('date')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`__gte` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte)

```
Event.objects.filter(date_from__gte=now).order_by('date')
```

Django's ORM is smart enough to honor datetime v/s date